# CMake broken after update to Xcode 7.0

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, xcode7

I use QtCreator and CMake for c++ development on a Mac, after updating to Xcode 7.0, CMake seems broken, after running CMake I got this warning:

> CMake Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/HEAD/share/cmake/Modules/Platform/Darwin-Initialize.cmake:128 (message): Ignoring CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT value:
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk
>
> because the directory does not exist. Call Stack (most recent call first): /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/HEAD/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInitialize.cmake:18 (include) CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

and build, I got this error:

> *** No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework'

I know that Xcode 7.0 has removed MacOSX10.10.sdk and added MacOSX10.11.sdk, so I thought it might be my cmake is too old, I updated my cmake to 3.3.2 with homebrew but still doesn't work, does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen in a clean repository that you just setup, or are you working in a dirty repository that predates the upgrade? It's possible that your `CMakeCache.txt` was configured before the upgrade and contains a reference to the old directory. If so, you can try deleting your `CMakeCache.txt` and reconfiguring.

Comment: hmm, thank @Alex, it was indeed the CMakeCache.txt issue, but not in my current project folder, my current project folder was a clean repo, but one of the dependency had a old CMakeCache.txt

Comment: Sounds good. I see you added your own answer, go ahead and accept it so that future visitors can see it.

Comment: I had to change/update the `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` path.

Answer (score 65):

delete any old CMakeCache.txt in current project and dependencies and rebuild solves the problem.

Answer (score 20):

If someone is using Clion you can try

> `Tools` > `CMake` > `Reset cache and reload project`

Comment: Invalidating cache won't worked for me. I have to manually delete cmake output files(`cmake-build-release`, etc..) and reloaded the cmake project.

Comment: Invalidating caches works to solve issues with paths to compiler components, although some garbage still remain in cmake-build-* folders cached and manual deletion and re-running CMake eliminates all issues completely

Answer (score 6):

The default value for `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` appears to be baked into the `cmake` executable, and automatically added to newly-created `CMakeCache.txt` cache files.

So I needed to **both** upgrade cmake **and then** delete all my `CMakeCache.txt` files to get CMake working again.